# C++ code not doing what I want

Tags: c++, function, cout

When I call this function it doesn't display any *. But when I change == to < it works. Why?

```
void starBox(int size){
    for(int i = 0; i == size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j == size; j++){
            cout << '*';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `i == size` only matches that one specific case.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I can potentially help you better if you tell me what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is due to misunderstanding of what the condition in the middle of `for` loop means. This is a loop *continuation* condition, meaning that the loop needs it to be `true` to proceed. Loop's post-condition is the inverse of its continuation condition.

> When I call this function it doesn't display any `*`.

This is because the loop continuation condition is `false` unless `size` is zero, so loop body is skipped.

> But when I change `==` to `<` it works. Why?

Because the loop continuation condition becomes `true`, and stays `true` until the loop is over. That is why `<` works; `!=` would work as well.